# How to benchmark/compare wireless and powerline network?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I want to use my home network for internet gaming, internet movie streaming, local movie streaming (desktop pc to Raspberry Pi) and remote gaming (desktop to Steam Link). I currently have a 100mbps internet connection and an AC wireless router (which gives me a real network speed of >100mbps).

1.) How can I test the quality of my wireless network? Especially in terms of latency and stability (no micro-lags whatsoever)? I have a desktop and a laptop for testing (but no raspberry pi or steam link yet).

2.) A friend of mine gave me his unused powerline adapters (1200mbps advertised) for testing. I guess, I can use the same testing tools as for my wireless network to compare their performances?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Note that powerline adapters depend on the quality of your electrical wiring and whether the adapters cross different electrical circuits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For simple testing**

For latency testing you can use MTR (or WinMTR or similar) to continuously monitor latency for a while.

For throughput, simply download a file from 1 server to another.

**For more advanced tests**

Use [iPerf](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php).  IPerf is a network testign tool designed specifically to test bandwidth, latency, jitter and packet loss.   There are a lot of tests you can perform - have a look for some examples [here](https://www.veritas.com/support/en_US/article.HOWTO64302).

Comment: Thanks. WinMTR and iPerf are great. Also PingPlotter is a nice alternative to WinMTR, with slightly more features.